# jQuery doesn't know function scrollTop

Tags: jquery, scrolltop, vertical-scrolling

I want do create a div, which is scrollable in y-direction, but is fixed in x-direction.
I already got help with it, here it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q4dWz/

But somehow it doesn't want to work at home.
I've downloaded the latest jquery:

```
wget -O jquery-1.5.min.js http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js
```

Everytime i call scrollTop I get it says that scrollTop is not a function :(
http://gbimg.org/p.php?q=BRYaL
I do not understand why it is not a function, and I don't understand, why Firebug says something about jquery 1.2.1 (look at the picture).
Here is the code:

```
160 $(document).ready(function() {
161     $(window).scroll(function(){
162         var $win = $(window);
163         $('#zeit').css('top', 20 - $win.scrollTop());
164     });
165-238 some other functions
238 });
```

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with your code. Could you post another jsfiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Can you show more of the `<head>` (or wherever you're pulling in scripts) from the page where this doesn't work?  You're probably including the very old jQuery version somewhere and not noticing.

Comment: `scrollTop()` wasn't added to jQuery until 1.2.6 and from your image it appears you are still using jQuery 1.2.1.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the useless $ before the win declartion? In JS you do not start a "normal" variable with $ like in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Likely you have a collision with the `$` variable in your home environment being set to two jQuery versions, and thus `var $win = $(window);` is setting `$win` to a jQuery 1.2.1 object without the required `scrollTop` function. If you look at the [jQuery scrollTop page](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#), you will see that `scrollTop` was introduced in version 1.2.6.

Comment: This is weired, because I never had installed jquery 1.2.1

Comment: @Mischka, what does your script reference look like?

Comment: @Mischka it's also a good idea to look at the script files that are loaded for the page using firebug. This will tell you the name of the script, and you can probably dig up the incorrect script reference from its name.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you are using the Latest version of jQuery.
`<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type = text/javascript" ></script>`

Also It's a good practice to use `parseInt()` we doing calculations.

`$('#zeit').css('top', parseInt(20-$win.scrollTop()));`

Comment: `scrollTop` always returns a number, and `-` is always an arithmetic operator in JS, so I'm skeptical of the utility of calling `parseInt` on the argument.

Comment: I agree. It's a good habit making use of it when dealing with variables or functions that generates intergers. It also makes it easier reading the code.